# What permission i set for application on facebook so that user can set photo/video on application wall?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

in my application i provide facility to user that he can post feed (image/video/text) on application profile page.

I have check graph/REST api for facebook but not find any way to post image/video on application page.

please provide a hint or tutorial regarding that.Also what permission i have to set on WEB (i.e. on facebook).

i can post text data successfully. But  problem arise in image/video.

Also feed publish in way FIRSTNAME_LASTNAME  >> APPLICATION_ NAME

note: user publish feed on application wall using application (also publish image/video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need permissions to user_photos,user_videos and publish_stream, take a look here for docs:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

What you want to do is create a post with attachment. Take a look at documentation here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

And here is a nice tutorial with example code you can download:
http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2